# How to change list(select) data dynamically

Tags: java, javascript, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I am adding product details.
So for that with it I have to add product attribute, product feature with it.

I am loading all data of attribute from mysql table.

I am using one mechanism that first user have to select attribute category from list (select control), when user select category then as per it data of other list (select control) changes.

**main category image :**

[image: category main]

**sub attribute category :**

[image: sub category]

I have added data like this in JavaScript array :

```
var at_category_id = [];
var at_category_name = [];

<%
    List<Integer> aIDList = (List<Integer>) request.getAttribute("aID");
    List<String>  aNAMEList = (List<String>) request.getAttribute("aNAME"); 

    for (int i = 0; i < aIDList.size(); i++) 
    {
     %>
        at_category_id.push(<%= aIDList.get(i) %>);
        at_category_name.push(<%= aNAMEList.get(i) %>);
    <%
    }
%>

var option_str = document.getElementById('list_main_category');

    for (var i=0; i<at_category_id.length; i++) 
    {
        option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(at_category_id[i],at_category_name[i]);
    }
```

I have done same like this for attribute and add data to JavaScript array.

```
var at_id = [];
var at_name = [];

<%
    List<Integer> acIDList = (List<Integer>) request.getAttribute("acID");
    List<String>  acNAMEList = (List<String>) request.getAttribute("acNAME");   

    for (int i = 0; i < aIDList.size(); i++) 
    {
     %>
        at_id.push(<%= acIDList.get(i) %>);
        at_name.push(<%= acNAMEList.get(i) %>);
    <%
    }
%>
```

but now how to move forward I don't know.

I want to do something like that.

[image]

Means when user click on first list that is main category how second list will be changed ?

any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way would be to put a javascript action on the value changing for the first combo box.

At that point you can either (easy way) submit the whole form and then send back the new page with the extra value added or (slightly more complex) do an AJAX call to fetch the data and populate the new dropdown.

Comment: That i know sir to call function on `onchange='functionName()'`. but if i ll get simple example then it would be better for me. because I have not enough knowledge of JavaScript.

Comment: <form:select path="model" onchange="this.form.submit()">

Comment: (That was in Spring, for a standard select just use the onchange and ignore the rest)

Comment: Yes I am doing that in simple jsp, I want simple example.

Comment: Sir I have updated question, I have added image that will show which type of mechansm i want.

Comment: Display first list. When they select submit the form, in the new form display both first two lists. When they select submit and in the new form display all three lists, etc.

Comment: Sir it's dynamic, how can I use in different form ?  I want it on one form. and without submit. on select one item second display.

Comment: You want AJAX then. Google it, there are plenty of tutorials online.

Comment: Okay let me try. Thank you.